# Excel VBA Getting a #Value error when trying to write a function for an array

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I am trying to find the shortest string in an array from a worksheet. However, when I try to execute the function I get a #Value error. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
Function ShortestString(ByVal array1 As Range)

Dim nRows As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim cell As String
Dim cellLength As Integer
Dim string1 As String

nRows = array1.Rows.Count
cellLength = 100
cell = array1.Cells(i, 1).Value

For i = 1 To nRows
    If cellLength > Len(cell) Then
    cellLength = Len(cell)
    string1 = cell
    End If
Next i

ShortestString = string1

End Function
```

Comment: `i` is 0 when you make this call: `cell = array1.Cells(i, 1).Value`. `nRows` should also be declared as `Long` - it can overflow if you have too many rows in the worksheet. You also need to cast `cell` to a string before you use `Len(cell)` - otherwise you'll get the length in bytes of the underlying data type.

Comment: `cell` is also never updated inside the loop. You should also add a check to see if `array1` actually contains more than one cell.

Comment: This worked, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues in your code.

- First, you never assign `i` before you call `cell = array1.Cells(i, 1).Value`. That's going to be a run-time error 1004.
- Second, you should test the input `Range` to make sure it's an "array" before you do anything else. If it's a single cell, you can skip everything else and just return the text of that cell.
- Third, you never update the value of `cell` anywhere in your function - it will always be the uninitialized value of `vbNullString`.
- Fourth, the maximum cell text length is 32767 characters, not 100. You should use that as your initial value.

My guess is that you're looking for something more like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function ShortestString(ByVal target As Range) As String
    Dim rowCount As Long, columnCount As Long
    rowCount = target.Rows.Count
    columnCount = target.Columns.Count

    If rowCount = 1 And columnCount = 1 Then
        ShortestString = target.Text
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim rowIdx As Long, colIdx As Long
    Dim shortest As String, current As String
    shortest = String(32767, " ")

    For rowIdx = 1 To rowCount
        For colIdx = 1 To columnCount
            current = target.Cells(rowIdx, colIdx).Text
            If Len(current) <= Len(shortest) Then
                shortest = current
            End If
        Next
    Next

    ShortestString = shortest
End Function
```

Note that you can probably actually *use* an array instead of testing individual cells, but that's an optimization you can make if the performance isn't up to snuff.

---

**Edit:**

You can convert the function to use an array of cell values by reading the entire range into a `Variant()`:

```
Dim cellValues() As Variant
cellValues = target.Value

For rowIdx = 1 To rowCount
    For colIdx = 1 To columnCount
        current = CStr(cellValues(rowIdx, colIdx))
        If Len(current) <= Len(shortest) Then
            shortest = current
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Hi, how would I convert this to use an array :)